# How do i obtain a key, value pair from a python dictionary referencing by a specific key

Tags: python, dictionary

Am I missing something obvious?
Given d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 10}
how do I get
{'b': 2} or even ('b', 2) or ['b', 2] just by providing 'b'?
Using a comprehension to iterate through the whole dictionary seems wildly inefficient and unnecessary since the whole point of a dictionary is to provide quick access by key.

My actual use for this is in a larger statement where I want to pass a single item from one dictionary appended to another dictionary, like so:
a = func({**d1['b'],**d2})
but of course that doesn't work because d1['b'] is not a dictionary.

I can do this with
result = {'b': d['b']}
but this seems clunky, especially when 'b' is actually a long string. Isn't there a cleaner way?

Comment: You already HAVE the key.  So, you'd do `(key: d[key]}`.  Right?  I think you're making this harder than it needs to be.

Comment: It's not clunky. It's perfectly reasonable.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, That's what I'm going to do. Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand your concern. However, I don't see why it is so bad to use it this way `{'b': d['b']}`. At least, it is clear what you do here. The only suggestion I would do is to use the get function from dict, unless you want the error message when the entry is not valid.

Also, dictionaries are optimized for cpu usage since they are hash tables. Your key 'b' is hashed to find the related value. Therefore, using `{'b': d['b']}` or even `{'b': d.get('b')}` (to avoid errors) would both be efficient. Your method is efficient and clear even if it does not look fancy.

Hopefully you won't get stuck on that one!

Answer (score 1):

You don't even have to construct new dictionary, simply call the function with `b=d1['b']`:

```py
def my_func(a, b, c):
    print(f"{a=} {b=} {c=}")


d1 = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 10}
d2 = {"a": 10, "c": 20}

my_func(b=d1["b"], **d2)
```

Prints:

```
a=10 b=2 c=20
```

Comment: The function only takes a single dictionary parameter